# Why is my base case being (erroneously) triggered immediately?

Tags: c, recursion, pass-by-value, stack-frame, pointer-aliasing

I am trying to implement a merge sort algorithm in C. In the recursive array split function, my base case is occurring infinitely, despite the return statement, and  the merge function is never called. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int MAX = 1000;

int getArray(int unsorted[MAX], int upperBound)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <= upperBound; ++i)
    {
        printf("Now enter integer number %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &unsorted[i]);
        while((getchar()) != '\n');
    }   
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int merge(int unsorted[MAX], int sorted[1000], int lowerLeft, int lowerRight)
{
    if(lowerLeft == lowerRight)
        return 0;
    int j = lowerRight;
    for(int i = lowerLeft; i < lowerRight; ++i)
    {
        if(unsorted[i] <= unsorted[j])
        {
            sorted[i] = unsorted[i];
            ++j;
        }
        else
        {
            sorted[i] = unsorted[j];
            ++j;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int split(int unsorted[MAX], int sorted[1000], int lowerBound, int upperBound)
{
    printf("%d is the lBound and %d is the uBound\n", lowerBound, upperBound);
    if(lowerBound == upperBound)
    {
        printf("\nBase case triggered.");
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
    int middle = upperBound/2;
    split(unsorted, sorted, 0, middle);
    split(unsorted, sorted, middle + 1, upperBound);    
    merge(unsorted, sorted, lowerBound, middle);
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int unsorted[MAX];
    int sorted[MAX];
    int lowerBound = 0;
    int upperBound;

    printf("First enter the number of integers you wish to sort: ");
    scanf("%d", &upperBound);
    while((getchar()) != '\n');
    printf("\n");
    upperBound = upperBound - 1;
    getArray(unsorted, upperBound);
    split(unsorted, sorted, lowerBound, upperBound);
    printf("\n");
    for(int c = 0; c < upperBound; ++c)
    {
        printf("%d, ", sorted[c]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Why won't the merge function be called after reaching the base case? Sorry if I didn't phrase the question conveniently, hoping someone can help me out here, thanks.

Comment: It often helps to put a `printf` right at the top of the recursive function, and print the arguments being passed to the function, i.e. the lower and upper bounds. Then you'll see that the base case is *not* being triggered immediately.

Comment: OT:  regarding the statement: `while((getchar()) != '\n');` in function: `main()`.  should also be checking against EOF, similar to: `int ch;   while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF );

Comment: OT:  regarding: `scanf("%d", &upperBound);`  When calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Note: those functions return the number of successful 'input format conversion specifiers'  Suggest: if( scanf("%d", &upperBound) != 1 ) { // handle error }`

Comment: regarding; `int middle = floor(upperBound/2);`  the expression: `upperBound/2` is an integer division and integer division always drops the fractional part.  The function: `floor()` expects a `double` parameter AND returns a `double` value`  Strongly suggest completely removing the call(s) to `floor()`  (which also means the header file: `math.h` can be removed.  Note: the posted code does not use anything from the `stdlib.h` header file, so that header file can also be removed

Comment: OT:  the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 1000.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statement(s) to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: Please when you change the posted code, please include a `EDIT` section.  Other wise, many of the comments are rendered meaningless.

Comment: OT:  regarding statements like: `printf("\nUpper half split, lbound = %d, ubound = %d", lowerBound, upperBound);`  Please include a '\n' at the end of the format string, otherwise the data output after the last '\n' will sit in the `stdout` buffer rather than being directly output to the terminal

Answer (score 1):

Your base case is being triggered because that's how recursive algorithms work. You keep calling `split()` over and over again with a lower and lower gap between lowerBound and upperBound, so eventually your base case gets triggered. And that should be a good thing, since triggering the base case lets you know that your input "arrays" (singletons) are sorted and can be merged.

The reason it gets triggered "immediately" is that it must: split() gets called continually until the base case is met, so the first print statement you'll see is the base case one.

Comment: Thanks for the input, user3629249. I added the updated code with the merge function, and eliminated the floor function and math library altogether. I also added the newlines after each printf. I also declared a constant global integer called MAX.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I took user3386109 advice and added a printf statement at the very beginning of the recursive function. You're right, the base case is not triggered immediately, however the split function continues to recurse infinitely, and I am not sure why it is doing this. Can you point me in the right direction? Thanks